# Python Program: Retrieving Follower Count and Displaying Person Details Returns None

Tags: python, list, nonetype

```
from game_data import data
from art import logo, vs
import random
print(logo)


person_one_list = []

person_two_list = []

person_first_followers = None
person_second_followers = None

def person_one():
    global person_first_followers

    # Select a random person from the data
    person = random.choice(data)
    person_one_list.append(person)  # Append the selected person to the list
    person['follower_count'] = person_first_followers  # Assign follower count

    # Print information about the selected person
    print(f"Compare A: {person['name']}, {person['description']}, from {person['country']}")
    print(f"Follower count inside person_one(): {person_first_followers}")


person_one()  # Now person_first_followers should have the correct value
print(f"Follower count outside person_one(): {person_first_followers}")

print(vs)

def person_two():
    """A function that generates a second random person and stores it into another list"""
    for person in range(1):
        person = random.choice(data)
        second_person = person_two_list.append(person)
        person_second_followers = person['follower_count']
        print(f"Against B: {person['name']}, {person['description']}, from {person['country']} ")


person_two()
print(person_second_followers)
choice = input("Who has more followers? Type 'A' or 'B' ")
```

This Python program aims to randomly select a person from a dataset and display their details, including their name, description, and country. Additionally, it retrieves the follower count of the selected person and assigns it to another value,however everytime I print the variable it returns none.`

Comment: "print the variable", which variable? Show at least a sample of `data`, better try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: In `person_one()`, should that say `person_first_followers = person['follower_count']`? You're printing out `person_first_followers` but unless I'm missing something you never give it a value other than `None` at the very start...

Comment: I want to add follower_count from the data list and assign its value to a variable 'person_first_followers' and 'person_second_followers'

Comment: @LeoD: Yes... but in `person_one()` you seem to be setting it the wrong way around - you are setting `person[...]` from `person_first_followers` (which is `None`) instead of the other way (in `person_two()` it is OK).

Comment: I'd suggest you reduce this to a [mcve], I'm sure you will find the error on the way. Generally, don't set things outside of a function (global vars) from inside the function. In other words, avoid function with side effects. Return the info from the function instead. If you need to return multiple values, you can return a tuple, too.